# What is PLS INTEGER?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqldatatypes

Is someone can explain what is PLS Integer in oracle pl/sql with an example?
Thanks

```
declare
  idx pls_integer :=1;
begin
  ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`pls_integer` (link)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS319) is a data type just like `number` or `date` or `varchar2`.  `pls_integer` is more efficient than the `number` data type because it consumes a bit less space and is faster for computations since it uses hardware arithmetic rather than library arithmetic.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you also explain when we should use binary_integer and when pls_integer?

Comment: @Ankit - From the documentation I linked to "The PL/SQL data types PLS_INTEGER and BINARY_INTEGER are identical"

Comment: @Ankit the history is that `binary_integer` existed first, then `pls_integer` came along around Oracle 7 as the improved version, then eventually around Oracle 10g they became the same thing. (Both only exist in PL/SQL and not in SQL, in case that wasn't clear.)